# Php get/iterate the values of a particular session

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Hy Guys
I don't understand how create the code for save inside the sessions, these different values.
This is an example of result of single session:
First array contains two different products
Second array contains the first name of user logged
Third array contains the last name of user logged

[image]

Thx a lot.

i have solved it, thanks to your help I understand how the sessions works.

```
// fist and last name of user
$_SESSION['nome'] = $_POST['nome'];
$_SESSION['cognome'] = $_POST['cognome'];

// here add the article inside the session
$_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['productCode']] = [
'article' => $_POST['productName'],
'price' => $_POST['buyPrice'],
'quantity' => $_POST['num_prodotto']
];

// for add the quantity for the same product 
$_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['productCode']]['quantity']+=$_POST['num_prodotto'];
```

Comment: why do you create 3 sessions? One is not enough?

Comment: because the first session is only for the products in my cart. It I create 1 session. if I create one session with all the variables I can't divide the elements

Comment: Divide what elements?

Comment: the first array contains the products, second array contain the name of user the third array contain the last name of user

Comment: And what's the problem: `$_SESSION['cart']`, `$_SESSION['first_name']`, `$_SESSION['second_name']`?

Comment: if I add another product inside the _SESSION['cart'] the product's can't add inside the session, but update the product previously inserted

Comment: So, the problem is that you can't insert data to session? How should three sessions help?

Comment: three sessions help me because the if I could to understand how iter/get values for the first session,  take the values of the cart is easy way.

Comment: Three sessions is __redundant__. Use only one.

Comment: if a create $_SESSION['cart'] and add item in a cart update the product previously inserted, that's why the session is created with "product id" $_SESSION[S10_1678].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for 3 sessions, use one session.

Your code can be something like:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['nome'] = 'nome';
$_SESSION['cognome'] = 'cognome';
// for this case the cart is empty:
$_SESSION['cart'] = [];

// add a product:
$article = 'A-1';
$_SESSION['cart'][$article] = [
    'article' => $article,
    'price' => 100,
    'quantity' => 1,
];

print_r($_SESSION);

// add second product:
$article = 'A-2';
$_SESSION['cart'][$article] = [
    'article' => $article,
    'price' => 100,
    'quantity' => 1,
];

print_r($_SESSION);

// update quantity under article A-1:
$article = 'A-1';
$_SESSION['cart'][$article]['quantity'] += 1;

print_r($_SESSION);
```